# python selenium accessing html elements on more than two levels

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver

I have a page that has to be scrapped.I use the python code

```
div = driver.find_element_by_class_name("parent")
data = div.find_elements_by_class_name("child1")
//I cannot access the web elements of **data** for eg: data.find_elements_by
for tag in data
     //I cannot print the information of each div here
```

the  Html

```
<div class="Parent">
    <div class = child1 >
        <div class = "heading">
            data
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = child1 child2 >strong text
        <div class = "heading">
            <span>data</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to access data

Comment: @op Need more info...couldnt understand the question properly. include more examples

Comment: There are two questions. 1. How to loop through the data when a div within a div has different class names. As I cannot use the functions find_element   multiple times to access through the dom structure

Comment: There are two questions. 1. How to loop through the data when a div within a div has different class names. As I cannot use the functions find_element   multiple times to access through the dom structure 2. Techniques to navigate through the dom structure that generates javascript at runtime. I cannot use beautifulsoup as it cannot read javascript at runtime @karthik27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can access html tags or text in different ways *http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html*
For multiple elements you can use :

```
find_elements_by_name
find_elements_by_xpath
find_elements_by_link_text
find_elements_by_partial_link_text
find_elements_by_tag_name
find_elements_by_class_name
find_elements_by_css_selector
```

There isn't a simple solution as far as I'm aware only by having specifics about the information you're looking for.
For instance let's you're using xpath (my personal preference):
Absolute XPath :

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/footer/section[3]/div/ul/li[3]/a
We can use Absolute xpath: /html/body/div[2]/div/div/footer/section[3]/div/ul/li[3]/a
```

> Above xpath will technically work, but each of those nested
>   relationships will need to be present 100% of the time, or the locator
>   will not function.  Above choosed xpath is known as Absolute xpath.
>   There is a good chance that your xpath will vary in every release. It
>   is always better to choose Relative xpath, as it helps us to reduce
>   the chance of element not found exception.

```
Relative xpath: //*[@id=’social-media’]/ul/li[3]/a
```

We can have a different approach to the data, therefore by using the correct way to 'select' the data we need, we can only extract/select the needed information. Look into each of these methods to understand them better, because you're asking for one line of code and each of those have their pros/cons (times when they can be useful or not).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to access text which is inside heading div, if it is so then you can try the below code.

```
element=driver.find_element_by_class_name("heading")
data=element.text
```

Answer (score -1):

assuming you are asking a way to loop through data where the info present is located in different locators in different nesting levels

There are multiple ways,

1. look for various selectors that match your pattern - find a way to do it that matches your problem - you refer css/xpath selector reference
2. if there are many selectors( but consistenly being used), you can use ByChained/ByAll Selectors look for the implementation in java, it will be like this, you can mimic the implementation,

   ```
   selector1 = .Heading .child2
   selector3 = .Heading .child3 span
   selector2 = .Heading .child1
   ByAll(selector1,selector2,selector3)'
   ```
3. if the parent is the only matching selector and there's no way to know abt child selectors, then another way is to use innerText/textContent property from a common parent

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ('.child1').getAttribute('innerText')
   ```

if none of these, solves your problem, and you application is dynamic enough to use different references and different nesting levels each time for all the page, then it was meant to be not scrapped. so your should look for other ways of scrapping it.